# Strange symbols while linking shared library g++

Tags: linux, g++, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, symbols

I have a file with the `void initGui()` function in it. It does stuff.
I also have a `.so` shared library made with that file.

The problem is, when I try to launch a `dlsym(..., "initGui")`, `dlerror()` tells me that it didn't found the symbol (of course, I used `dlopen` to open it). So I tried to `nm` my shared lib. I "understood" that `_Z7initGuiiii` might be what I'm looking for. So I tried to `dlsym` it ... And it worked.

Please can someone tell me how to have clean symbols in my shared object library ?

I compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c -fPIC`.

Comment: This is C++ name mangling. However I don't know the answer for your question. It's a good question.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: http://www.isotton.com/devel/docs/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual practice when `dlsym`-ing inside some `dlopen`-ed shared library coded in C++ is to have the convention that those seeked symbols (those that you are dlsym-ing) are declared `extern "C"`. Then their name is easily visible with `dlsym`. So you need to declare

```
 extern "C" void initGui(void);
```

and then to do

```
 typedef void initguiroutine_sig_t(void);
 initguiroutine_sig_t* initguiptr = dlsym(dlhandle,"initGui");
 if (!initguiptr) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "initGui not found: %s\n", dlerror());
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
 };
 // later, call initguiptr like
 (*initguiptr) ();
```

I don't recommend understanding in great details how your [C++ name mangling works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), it is not very well defined, and details depend upon particular version of the C++ libraries (notably the standard C++ library) and of the compiler version.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers !